# uploadede file path django

Tags: python, django

in  forms.py:

```
image = forms.ImageField(upload_to="images/")
```

in settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = (
os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "media")
)
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

in views.py:

```
c_image = UploadedFile(request.FILES.get('image'))
pathe=c_image.temporary_file_path


sql = "INSERT INTO client (name, address, email, gender, country, sub_priod ) VALUES \
                          ('%s', '%s', '%s','%s', '%s', '%s')" % \
                          (c_name, c_address, c_email, c_gender, c_country, pathe )
```

error:

```
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:type object 'UploadedFile' has no attribute 'temporary_file_path'
```

what should i do ?

Comment: There may be no file path at all -- per https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/files/uploads/ , it might be an `InMemoryUploadedFile` (by default, that happens for files < 2.5MB) -- so, you can't persist a "path" that might just not be there:-)

Comment: What is the point of this code? You are recreating functionality already available in django.

Comment: i think i need to change first tow lines.but what to change.
i don't know...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import ModelFormWithFileField

def upload_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ModelFormWithFileField(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
        # file is saved
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/url/')
    else:
        form = ModelFormWithFileField()
    return render(request, 'upload.html', {'form': form})
```